# From Analytics data, easy way to get % of visitors with a screen resolution of X or larger

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, resolution

Is there any easy way to use the Analytics data of a website, for example on google analytics, and query it to get the % of users with a browser resolution of X or larger?

It's good to know the top used resolutions but for example I want to know if I can drop support for very small resolutions so it would be nice to know the % of users using 1024 or smaller for example.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to achieve this somewhere in G-Analytics or an external tool. Right now I'm parsing the raw data and doing this on a custom program I did.

Comment: Are you setting this as a custom variable in Google Analytics?   I don't see any screen size or resolution data in any of my reports.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Audience > Technology > Browser & OS and then you have to click on Primary dimension 'filter' to Screen Resolution: https://imgur.com/wQps2kM